# Height of the individual elements using jQuery height();

Tags: jquery, height

I have an unordered list. In each of the list-items I have div's with text content in it. So, first list-item may just have one line of text & the next might even have more than three lines of text.

I am trying to get the height of these div's using (jQuery API - height();) as & when I hover over each of the list-items.

The problem is that every time, I get the height of the first list-item no matter which list-item I hover over.

**.quickHover is my div's class name.**

Here's my code:

```
var divHeight = $('.quickHover').height();

$('.catProductlist li').hover(

function () {
    $(this).find('.quickHover').animate({
        bottom: '0'
    }, 'fast');
}, function () {
    $(this).find('.quickHover').animate({
        bottom: '-' + divHeight + 'px'
    }, 'fast');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/height/

> Get the current computed height for the **first element** in the set of matched elements.

Why don't you calculate div's height IN the hover function?

Answer (score 0):

+1 to MatTheCat:

```
$('.catProductlist li').hover(

var divHeight = $(this).find('.quickHover').height();

function () {
    $(this).find('.quickHover').animate({
        bottom: '0'
}, 'fast');
}, function () {
    $(this).find('.quickHover').animate({
    bottom: '-' + divHeight + 'px'
}, 'fast');
});
```